# unrecognized option --gc-keep-exported on arm ld

Tags: gcc, arm, robotics, arm-none-eabi-gcc

Right now, I'm trying to integrate a GitHub Action that checks if some code on a pull request compiles properly (VEX Robotics for anyone interested). However, when it gets to running the `make` command, I get this error:

```
Building Project
make: Entering directory '/github/workspace/V5'
Adding timestamp [OK]
Creating cold package with libpros,okapilib [ERRORS]
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--gc-keep-exported'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/cold.package.elf] Error 1
common.mk:200: recipe for target 'bin/cold.package.elf' failed
```

I'm extremely confused as to why this is occurring? `--gc-keep-exported` [is a real option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html), and this code compiles perfectly on my local machine. I've tried changing the ubuntu version and updating the VEX SDK to see if it helps, but I keep on getting the same error. What should I do?

### Code:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

# Install GCC & Clang
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install clang -y

# Install needed ARM deps
RUN apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi -y
RUN apt-get install binutils-arm-none-eabi -y

# Install 7z & cURL
RUN apt-get install p7zip-full -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`entrypoint.sh`:

```
echo "Downloading VEX SDK"
# Get VEX SDK and put it in ~/sdk
curl -L https://content.vexrobotics.com/vexcode/v5code/VEXcodeProV5_2_0_1.dmg -o _vexcode_.dmg
7z x _vexcode_.dmg || :
7z x Payload~ ./VEXcode\ Pro\ V5.app/Contents/Resources/sdk -osdk_temp || :
mkdir ~/sdk
mv sdk_temp/VEXcode\ Pro\ V5.app/Contents/Resources/sdk/* ~/sdk
rm -fR _vex*_ _vex*_.dmg sdk_temp/ Payload~
ls ~/sdk # ls just for testing

echo "Building Project"
# Now make the makefile in the set path
make --directory=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because I used an old version of `gcc-arm-none-eabi`. The version on apt is super outdated (`v6.3.1` vs `v10.2.1`).

I was able to use the new version by downloading the tarball available on their [site](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) and using the direct paths to compile my code.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to base your container on Ubuntu 18.04?  More recent Ubuntu versions have more recent gcc versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer GCC version available for a newer Ubuntu version, you could browse for another one, or be lazy and enjoy some malpractice with me:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```